# Views-How do i redirect to the same page after saving the comment?

Tags: views, comments

Sorry Guys , i have an easy question!

i used views to create a page that contains a kind of content with comment!

the link is "http://mydomain/testpage"

but when i write the comment on the content which is displayed by the view, the system will go to the "http://mydomain/node/%"

how can i stay at the same page after i writting the comment in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i fix the problem, i just use the page management and change the setting of the node view,give a content type variant and then user http response.

Problem fixed ~ if you have the same question, take a try!

Comment: i think i have a better solution,just use hook_node_submit and hook_node_insert. :)